# Missing API's while creating autodesk forge application

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I'm new to Autodesk Forge API. Planning to use it for converting Revit files. But when creating an app inside the Forge console, the system doesn't allow me to select relevant API's to "turn them on" for the app.
http://prntscr.com/hgb9ib

While https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/create-app/ guide lists all possible API's the service provides.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you did not start your trial, please apply for FREE 90-DAY TRIAL, and you will see all the available APIs in the list.

Comment: that's really the case. thanks a lot. I thought it would automatically sign me to a trial after a create dev account.

Comment: it's not sign you in the trail automatically, and provide you the ability to start to enroll into trail per your needs, but yes, it sometimes cause the confusion, I will communicate this back to the team to make the balance. Btw, could you please mark this as answer so others can know how to deal with this if meet same issue? thanks.